# click event fires twice for button inside link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create the stacked pills nav control.  Each entry in the control is a link, and that link element also contains a button.  The button may be clicked to delete the list entry, or the list entry itself may be clicked to perform some action on it.

The html for each list entry looks like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="launch_me">Some title
        <button class="my-class" id="remove_me">
             <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>

    </a>
</li>
```

These items are added dynamically based on a response from a server.  The jquery then adds the click handler via:

```
$("#launch_me").click((function (info) {
    return function () {
        launch(info);
    };
})(myInfo));

$("#remove_me").click((function (info) {
    return function () {
        remove(info);
    };
})(myInfo));
```

When I click on the button to delete the entry, the 'remove' click routine is triggered, followed by the launch routine.

How can I make it so clicking the remove button only results in the remove click handler being run?

Thanks!

Comment: Look up event bubbling.

Comment: Specifically, stopPropagation()  http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#remove_me").click((function (info) {
    return function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        remove(info);
    };
})(myInfo));
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

This will prevent the `click` event of the "Remove Me" button from bubbling up to its parent "Launch Me" container and executing its `click` handler.

Your before: http://jsfiddle.net/HVExt/

Mine after: http://jsfiddle.net/HVExt/1/

Answer (score 0):

MyInfo looks dodgy to me. I wiuld skip that and add ; instead. But then i don't know the rest of your code...